# boost python shared_ptr + virtual + overriding in python

Tags: boost-python

I would appreciate help making boost-python use a wrapper class I defined for an abstract base class to wrap derived classes.

I have an abstract C++ base class `baz`, and derived classes `foo` (not exposed) and `bar` (exposed to python). There is a factory function returning `boost::shared_ptr<baz>` pointing to instances of `foo`, and here I am hoping to get the `boost::shared_ptr<baz>` from the factory to be wrapped in `baz_callback`. I would also like to override `pure` in python, which seems to work for the base class `baz` (overridden in the `mumble` python class), but not for the derived class `bar` (overridden in `jungle`).

For illustration, I extended an [example](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/OverridableVirtualFunctions) from the python wiki, see below. All the printouts should have a 1 as second digit, coming from `baz_callback::pure`, but only the `mumble` version gets that right. For `jungle`, the python verion of `pure` is ignored, and the C++ version used instead.

File `override_shared.cc`:

```
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module_init.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/call_method.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

#include <boost/python/register_ptr_to_python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/pure_virtual.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

struct baz {
    virtual int pure(int) = 0;
    int calls_pure(int x) { return pure(x) + 1000; }
};

struct foo : baz {
    int pure(int i) { return i+10; };
};

struct bar : baz {
    int pure(int i) { return i+30; };
};

struct baz_callback : baz {
    baz_callback(PyObject *p) : self(p) {}
    int pure(int x) { return 100 + call_method<int>(self, "pure", x); }
    PyObject *self;
};

boost::shared_ptr<baz> make_foo()
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<foo>(new foo());
}

boost::shared_ptr<baz> make_bar()
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<bar>(new bar());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE_INIT(liboverride_shared)
{
     class_<baz, boost::shared_ptr<baz_callback>, boost::noncopyable>("baz")
         .def("pure", pure_virtual(&baz::pure))
         .def("calls_pure", &baz::calls_pure);

     class_<bar, bases<baz> >("bar");

     def("make_foo", make_foo);
     def("make_bar", make_bar);

     // I suspect the problem lies here:
     register_ptr_to_python< boost::shared_ptr<baz> >();
}
```

File `override_shared.py`:

```
from liboverride_shared import *

f = make_foo()

class mumble(baz):
    def pure(self, x): return x + 20
m = mumble()

class jungle(bar):
    def pure(self, x): return x + 40
j = jungle()

def check(name, bar, i, expected):
    actual = bar.calls_pure(i)
    msg = "ok" if actual == expected else ("bad, expected %d" % expected)
    print (name, actual, "--", msg)

check("foo", f, 1, 1111)
check("mumble", m, 2, 1122)
check("jungle", j, 4, 1144)
```

File `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0)

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp 3 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs "${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}" REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.58.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS "python-py${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ADD_LIBRARY(override_shared SHARED
  override_shared.cc
)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(override_shared ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```